# Is it possible to force deselection of all object onclick?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

My problem is that when I go to print a fabricjs canvas sometimes I'll forget to deselect an object and it leaves the controls on it when it goes to the print dialogue. Is there a way to clear any selected objects onclick?

Currently to print I'm using the following:

```
// Print
function printCanvas() {
var dataUrl = document.getElementById('c').toDataURL(); //attempt to save base64 string to server using this var  
  var windowContent = '<!DOCTYPE html>';
  windowContent += '<html>'
  windowContent += '<head><title>Print canvas</title></head>';
  windowContent += '<body>'
  windowContent += '<img src="' + dataUrl + '" onload=window.print();window.close();>';
  windowContent += '</body>';
  windowContent += '</html>';
  var printWin = window.open('', '', 'width=340,height=260');
  printWin.document.open();
  printWin.document.write(windowContent);
}
```

---

```
<button onclick="printCanvas()">Print</button>
```

From the print dialogue:

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
canvas.discardActiveObject();
canvas.renderAll();
```

```js
(function() {
    var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
  
    // create a rectangle with a fill and a different color stroke
    var rect = new fabric.Rect({
       left: 50,
       top: 50,
       width: 50,
       height: 50,
       fill: 'rgba(255,127,39,1)',
       stroke: 'rgba(34,177,76,1)',
       strokeWidth: 5
    });
    canvas.add(rect);
    canvas.renderAll();    
    $('#deselect').click(function(){
      canvas.discardActiveObject();
      canvas.renderAll();
    });
})();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="150" height="150"></canvas>
<button id="deselect">deselect</button>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.4.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How might I use what you've provided with my click button? I tried adding the functionality to what I have without luck